# Why is my member variable dissapearing at the end of each loop iteration?

Tags: c++

In the following loop, I am taking string variables from one vector and using them in the constructor for a bunch of elements that will be added to another constructor.

```
while (std::getline(qt_prim_file_stream, temp_str, '\n')) {
    if (temp_str.empty()) // Blank line implies new module
    {
      //output_wires is a vector of string
      std::string cur_output_wire=output_wires[m_hex_to_SOP.size()];
      SOPExpr expr(current_SOP_string, cur_output_wire);
      m_hex_to_SOP.push_back(expr);
      current_SOP_string.clear();
      i_3++;
      continue;
    }
    current_SOP_string.append(temp_str);
    current_SOP_string.push_back('\n');
    i_2++;
  }
```

My problem is that the second member string variable (m_output_wire) of SOPExpr in each SOPExpr in m_hex_to_SOP (a vector of SOPExpr) keeps dissapearing at the end of each loop (gets set to ""). Why is this happeing? The first member variable (m_gate_level_netlist) doesn't get set to "".

Here is the header for SOPExpr.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

    class SOPExpr {
        std::string m_gate_level_netlist;
        std::string m_output_wire;
    public:
        const std::string &getMOutputWire() const;
    public:
        SOPExpr(const std::string &m_gate_level_netlist);
        SOPExpr(const SOPExpr &expr);
        SOPExpr();
        SOPExpr(const std::string &mGateLevelNetlist, const std::string &mOutputWire);
        const std::string &getGateLevelNetList() const;
    };
```

and here is the class file:

```
#include "SOPExpr.h"

SOPExpr::SOPExpr(const SOPExpr &expr) {
  m_gate_level_netlist = expr.getGateLevelNetList();
}
SOPExpr::SOPExpr() {}
const std::string &SOPExpr::getGateLevelNetList() const {
  return m_gate_level_netlist;
}

SOPExpr::SOPExpr(const std::string &mGateLevelNetlist,
                 const std::string &mOutputWire)
    : m_gate_level_netlist(mGateLevelNetlist), m_output_wire(mOutputWire) {}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. -- *SOPExpr in each SOPExpr in m_hex_to_SOP (a vector of SOPExpr) keeps dissapearing* -- Maybe because it is a local variable within that loop?

Comment: "Why is my member variable dissapearing at the end of each loop iteration?"  Probably because of a bug.  Have you tried [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?  A nice example from a former coworker of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, m_hex_to_SOP is defined as std::vector, right?

In that case, when you call m_hex_to_SOP.push_back(expr); you are actually invoking this copy constructor:

```
SOPExpr::SOPExpr(const SOPExpr &expr) {
  m_gate_level_netlist = expr.getGateLevelNetList();
}
```

which does not copy m_output_wire.

Comment: Worth an edit to add on `SOPExpr`'s members are all Rule of Five compliant so `SOPExpr` can safely observe the Rule of Zero.

Comment: The `SOPExpr` didn't even need a user-defined copy constructor, since both members are already safely copyable by themselves (both are vectors).  This is an example of when a programmer jumps in, says "I know better", and overrides the (perfectly acceptable) compiler default version of the copy constructor with a buggy version.  Never write a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator if the compiler default versions are acceptable.  This is the risk you run of writing unnecessary code.